# Elastic search: query string specify decimal points

Tags: elasticsearch

I have data stored in ES as a double format. At UI, its value is displayed with two decimal points.

For eg. 0.33182782258064514 is shown as 0.33

When user does some filtering like equals filter then it sends 0.33 to the ES query via query string `fieldname:0.33`

This query fails because of difference in decimal points. Is there any way to specify that ES query should use 2 decimal points so that it will work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Double fields are precise. 0.33 is not 0.33182782258064514 even though it displays as 0.33 for convenience purposes.

How about specifying a range in your query string such as this one?

```
fieldname:[0.33 TO 0.34}
```

or

```
fieldname:>=0.33 AND fieldname:<0.34
```

Comment: If I pass only integer value then this won't work. Should I be checking if value is integer then just do fieldname:value otherwise do what you have suggested

Comment: Your question was about querying double values, but if you want to query integers, then yes, you can check if it is an integer first and check equality instead of range for integer values.

Comment: Thanks @Val. Let me try this

Comment: This works as intended. I have one more problem value like 0.809637096774193 gets converted to 0.81. I will need to some more checking I guess

Comment: Where does it gets "converted"? At indexing time or a query time?

Comment: At UI, I convert value into 2 decimal format and then same value is sent back to ES.

Comment: You said you had 2 decimal points on the display, how come it shows 3 now?

Comment: I think I should for 0.33 equality..query should be like
fieldname: { 0.3250000000000 to 0.33500000000}

Comment: And so the problem is that the user will search for 0.81... Well trying to match double values with 10+ decimals will always involve ranges, strict equality is difficult. What you could do is deduct 0.1 from the queried number to create the range, i.e. for 0.81, you'd create a range for 0.80 to 0.82, for instance.

Comment: Let's move to chat :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101045/discussion-between-ajinkya-pisal-and-val).